# ChatGPT create a new conversation with history

Tags: openai-api

I've tried for 3 days to find a way to create a conversation and keep the history somehow from my app. I want to create a chat app with history with ChatGPT but i didn't see any options/endpoints in theirs API to acomplish this.

I saw that the main chatGPT chat from their website is using a different endpoint that keeps the conversation history based on a conversation ID.

Is there any way to use that or another endpoint that does the same thing?

I will store the history on my side but i don't want to send it each time on the request. It will cost me tokens .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The only current solutions are to either make embeddings of the conversation history and build some logic to reference that history when making new requests or summarize the conversation on the backend end pass it as part of the prompt, which you are correct uses additional tokens.

Comment: Hello, is there any endpoint to reference to a history , because i saw none on their side

Comment: also what do you mean by embeddings of the conversation history? i do still need to pass the history in the request, right?

Comment: https://thoughtblogger.com/openai-embedding-tutorial/ This article describes embeddings.

Answer (score 3):

Like you have discovered, OpenAI doesn't natively provide the ability to store conversation memory, but there are open-source solutions to this:

1. https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain - It is a framework where you plugin ChatGPT, or any LLMs in general, into it, and the framework will take care of issues like conversation history
2. https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/chatgpt-api - this does the same as the above, except it is catered specifically to ChatGPT

I am going to use the 2nd solution because I don't need any customizability at this point. Let's face it, ChatGPT is going to be the only relevant LLMs for a very long time. They are both actively being worked on.

Comment: That second solution just handles sending the entire history for you, nothing more. You still have the same problem over time.

Comment: dearsina is correct. Also, the langchain option, while it natively supports persisting conversation, requires you to integrate it with external databases like MongoDB or Pinecone. Basically, if you want to have your conversations saved even if the server running ChatGPT crashes or restarts, you need to do extra work in either implementing your own storage or integrate it with an existing one.

Comment: Were you as surprised as I am when you found out about this seemingly gaping hole in the ChatGPT API? It's too expensive? Well then just charge more for those that opt for it?